# PySide: Setting setDisabled(True) for a child menu entry not working in Mac

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am creating a system tray application in Mac (El Capitan 10.11.3) using Pyside. However, I am not able to set certain menu entry as disabled, particularly when its a **child menu**. The `setDisabled(True)` works for **parent menu** entry though.

The same code works in Ubuntu/Linux and the child menu entry is disabled.

As the original code is too long to display here, I have made a simple sys tray application that exhibits the same problem.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):

    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(parent)
        menu.addAction("Item 1")
        menu.addAction("Item 2")
        disabledItem = menu.addAction("Item 3 Disabled")
        disabledItem.setDisabled(True)
        subMenu = menu.addMenu("Item 4 with sub menu")
        subMenu.addAction("SubMenu 1")
        disabledSubMenu = subMenu.addAction("SubMenu 2 Disabled (Not Working)")
        disabledSubMenu.setDisabled(True)
        disabledSubMenu2 = subMenu.addMenu("SubMenu Disabled")
        disabledSubMenu2.setDisabled(True)
        self.setContextMenu(menu)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    style = app.style()

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon(style.standardPixmap(QtGui.QStyle.SP_FileIcon)))

    trayIcon.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

From the above example, **Item 3 Disabled** (which is a parent menu) is disabled when using `setDisabled(True)`. But **SubMenu 2 Disabled** is not working, which is a **child menu** to **Item 4 with sub menu**.

One thing to note is **SubMenu Disabled** is working when its set as `addMenu` item than using `addAction`.

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaction.html#setDisabled
the name of the method is same with qmenu.But qmenu's set disabled is inherite from qwidget while qaction's method is only for itself and it's not for the user interface. also qaction is abstract what you can see is a qmenu actually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But one thing to note is, its actually working in other platforms. I have tested it in Ubuntu and child menu is disabled by using setDisabled(true). I am not sure about the behavior in windows. Will test & update the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#This is the example code for Setting setDisabled(True) for a child .
#If your are not expecting this answer, sorry.
#It is PyQt4, but you can try with PySide with small changes.

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Window (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):[![enter image description here][1]][1]      

        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)  

        menubar    = QtGui.QMenuBar (self)
        menubar.setObjectName('menubar')

        menu       = QtGui.QMenu(menubar)
        menu.setObjectName('menu')
        menu.setTitle ('File')
        menubar.addAction (menu.menuAction())    

        menu.addAction ("Item 1")       
        menu.addAction ("Item 2")    

        disabledItem    = menu.addAction("Item 3 Disabled")
        disabledItem.setDisabled(True)

        subMenu         = menu.addMenu("Item 4 with sub menu")
        subMenu.addAction ("SubMenu 1")       

        disabledSubMenu = subMenu.addAction("SubMenu 2 Disabled (Not Working)")
        disabledSubMenu.setDisabled (True)   

        disabledSubMenu2 = subMenu.addMenu("SubMenu Disabled")
        disabledSubMenu2.setDisabled(True)       

        self.resize(513, 203)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have tried setEnabled(False) & its also not working :(. Thanks for the suggestion though!